# How do I pass objects from NodeJS to javascript files with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Down below you can see I have a nodeJS server which passes down a data object to the index page. Inside of my index.ejs file I can receive this data using <%= data %> however this only gives [object Object]. However, what I want is to receive this data inside my javascript file as an acutal object so I can use the data to do stuff. How can I acheive this?

NodeJS:

```
router.get("/", getData, (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", { data: data }); // Where 'data' is a large object with lots of information 
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script defer src="myScript.js"></script> <!-- I want to pass the data object to this file -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= data %> <!-- This works, but is not what I want -->
  </body>
</html>
```

myScript.js:

```
const data = <%= data %> // this doesnt work, but is what I need
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a data exchange language based on literal syntax for JavaScript. So long as your data consists entirely of data types supported by JSON (such as plain objects and numbers) you can use it to generate a string that you can insert into a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and parse with [`JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
<script data-data="<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.data);
</script>
```

If your object includes features not supported by JSON, such as functions, symbols, etc. then you'll need to special case how they are transferred across.

---

An earlier version of this answer used a similar technique that treated the JSON as JavaScript source code. This more-or-less works, but is vulnerable to XSS since if the data contains a string  `"</script>"` that will terminate the script element in the middle of the string literal. There is a potential that further data in the string could pose a more serious XSS threat.

You could use that technique, but you would need to mitigate that attack by escaping `/` characters.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the error unexpected token "&" at this line

Comment: @OscarR — Ah, that was my mistake. `<%=` does HTML escaping and the data was being output into JS not HTML. There was an issue with that version of code which made it vulnerable to XSS (if the data included a string containing `</script>`). The new version should be better.

Comment: thank you, this works, wish I could upvote, but ill mark it as accepted atleast :)

Answer (score -2):

Try like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script>var data = <%= JSON.stringify(data) %>;</script>
    <script defer src="myScript.js"></script> <!-- I want to pass the data object to this file -->
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Security concern: If your object contain user supplied datas, your page will possibly become subject to injection

Comment: The value being passed is called `data`, not `name` and is an object (so you'll get `"[object Object]"` out of your code which will break it.

Comment: so this worked, but I am getting [object Object] when i try to console.log the data var now

Comment: @OscarR — Since you're getting `[object Object]` … it **didn't** work.

Comment: Re edit: That also won't work. Unless the object has no properties at all, the resulting JSON will include `"` characters which will terminate your string literal prematurely. Even if that wasn't the case, then *myScript.js* will have to deal with a string of JSON instead of the object it is expecting.

Comment: Re edit: Congratulations. After your edits you have landed on the same result as my answer.

Comment: Yes, and you have answered 6 minutes after me! Bravo!